# implode de columnas y filas de DataTable C#

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, insert

Estoy tratando de hacer una insercion de datos, de un dataTable cuyos datos han sido pasados de una consulta sql, Deseo volcar estos datos en otra tabla, tal y como vienen.

Esta funcion lo hará para varias tablas, por lo cual los nombres de columnas y la cantidad no las puedo definir en el codigo. la idea es ejecutar una consulta como la siguiente.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(COLUMN1, COLUMN2, ....) VALUES (VALUE1, VALUE2..)
```

En php existe la solucion de hacer un implode a los resultados.

```
$columns = implode(", ",array_keys($insData));
$escaped_values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($insData));
$values  = implode(", ", $escaped_values);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `fbdata`($columns) VALUES ($values)";
```

Pero en C# no tengo idea de como hacer el implode

Este es el codigo que tengo.

```
SqlDataReader datosAnfitrion = origen.ExecuteQuerySelect("Select * from "+datosFila.TablaOrigen+" "+datosFila.CondOrigen);
                DataTable schemaTable = datosAnfitrion.GetSchemaTable();

                var columnas= string.Join(",", schemaTable.AsEnumerable().Select(T =>
                T.ColumnName.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Sin embargo creo que ese codigo necesita, que especifique el nombre de la columna

Comment: Tu código parece correcto. Que problema tienes con el?

Comment: @Pikoh T.ColumnName me da error, igual lo resolví de otra manera.ya que no pude averiguar los nombres de columna, hice el insert directo, sin especificar las columnas, ahora el problema son los campos datetime, pero tendré que hacer otra pregunta.

Comment: Me alegro que lo resolvieses de otra manera. De todas maneras [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.datatablereader.getschematable(v=vs.110).aspx) tienes ejemplos para obtener el nombre de las columnas usando `GetSchemaTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si a alguien le sirve, ya encontré la solución

```
SqlDataReader datosAnfitrion = origen.ExecuteQuerySelect("Select * from mitabla");
            DataTable dt= new DataTable();
            dt.Load(datosAnfitrion);
            var columns = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName).ToList();
            var columnsParams = columns.Select(x => $"@{x}").ToList();
            var insertSql = $"INSERT INTO {datosFila.TablaDestino} ({string.Join(", ", columns)}) VALUES ({string.Join(", ", columnsParams)});";

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
             {

                using (MySqlCommand msc = new MySqlCommand(insertSql, destino.cnn))
                {
                    foreach (var column in columns) msc.Parameters.AddWithValue(column, dr[column]);                        
                    msc.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

             }
```